# ERROR: Plugin '' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml

Tags: ios, plugins, cordova

I tried to add 'NativeTable' plugin, to display tableview in my phonegap app.

i am getting error as "ERROR: Plugin '' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml".

I have added NativeTable.h and NativeTable.m file in plugins directory, NativeTable.js in www directory.

and also added `<plugin name="NativeTable" value="NativeTable" />`

in config.xml file, in cordova.plist a key/value pair Key:NativeTable Value:Nativetable is added in plugins dictionary.

Please help me out with a solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

You must check the location of the .h and .c file of the plugin. They must be in the plugins folder of the project. Triple check this is the case - as it is the only way the error can come about.

Comment: follow this blog for step by step implementation. http://csharpwavenet.blogspot.sg/2015/05/local-storage-with-sqlite-for-hybrid.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with the SQLitePlugin. Try removing and adding your platform again (in my case, it was platform/ios since I am developing for an iPhone). Then rebuild your project. It worked for me.